# What's the process with SSL certificate with Volley on Android

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, android-volley

I'm developing an Android App which requests a server with https. So the server has a certificate. During development I've managed to trust all certificates to not care about that at this stage of the project.
As I'm preparing the production phase, I would like to know how do I use volley with https, by verifying the authenticity of the server. Should I import something in the App ? May someone explains me how it works ? 
Please don't give me just a tutorial to follow, I've found some already but I'm facing difficulties to understand the process,  some explanations would be great !
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Which process you followed to get this sorted out ? Please tell me as I am suffering with the same problem right now..

Answer (score 0):

As long as the certificate comes from a valid Certificate Authority (CA) it will work as is.

This is the same with all android https connections.

You do not need to install certificates etc on the android device.

(You should double check the CA you are using is valid on the android as there are some that may not be compatible this easily. Although the majority should be)

Comment: What in case when I have to use my own CA. How to verify connection with my own CA certs?

Comment: @ESYSCODER try installing the certificate on the android. This may not be feasible to expect every user to do this though

Comment: Yes, this is not feasible. But already find a way to trust own CA using TrustManager in application.